# Pass data between controllers asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to know how to pass data between two controllers in asp.net mvc 3
i have two controllers

```
public class controller1:Controller
{
}

public class controller2:Controller
{
}
```

how to pass data from controller1 to controller2?

Comment: Normally this is not necessary. Can you specify your reasons? Maybe there is an alternative.

Comment: u want to pass data from action of controller1 to the action of controller2???

Comment: @Exception :yea from one action of controller1 to another action of controller2

Comment: @Stefan i need to pass the username from login controller to index action of another controller

Comment: as shown in my answer prefer to use routevalue try to avoid tempdata because during redirecting sometime it lost its value...thankzz..

Answer (score 2):

One way is to pass using `TempData`:

```
public class controller1Controller:Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    TempData["SomeKey"] = "Some Value";
    return RedirectToAction("Index","controller2");
  }
}

public class controller2Controller:Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    string value = TempData["SomeKey"] as String;
    return View();
  }
}
```

One thing to remember is `TempData` is single read, which means that once a value is read from `TempData` it will automatically be deleted, if the value is till needed after read and you want to persist it, you have to call `TempData.Keep()` and you can be more specific to persist specific key value by calling:

```
string value = TempData["SomeKey"] as String;
TempData.Keep("SomeKey");
```

Another way is to use **RouteValue Dictionary**:

```
public class controller1Controller:Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return RedirectToAction("Index","controller2",new { SomeKey = "SomeValue"});
  }
}

public class controller2Controller:Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index(string SomeKey)
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

I am using String in example, you can have a custom type like a model or view model object that is to be passed.

I would suggest you to read this [**MSDN article**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more details and understanding of passing data in mvc application.

You should also read [**What is ViewData, ViewBag and TempData? – MVC options for passing data between current and subsequent request**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-cplusViewBagplusandplusTem) and [**When to use ViewBag, ViewData, or TempData in ASP.NET MVC 3 applications**](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications)

Comment: no it is single read, after read it is auto deleted but if you want it to be there, after reading from tempdata call this: ``TempData.Keep("SomeKey")``, now this key value will be persisted

Comment: @user3894583 you should accept answer if problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You can use **RouteValue Dictionary** here as :-

```
public class controller1Controller:Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return RedirectToAction("Index","controller2",new { UserName= "Username"});  <----Just pass username value here
  }
}

public class controller2Controller:Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index(string UserName)   <-----get username value here
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```